# Create multiple schedulers in run time

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduler

I have the following requirement for which I have not found any solution yet. Any helpful tips / code snippets would be useful -

I have a spring boot app which connects to a PostgreSQL DB table which has thousands of columns in the format:

### id | cron_expression

### 1  | * * * * *

### 2  | * * * * *

Is it possible to programatically create separate Scheduled jobs for each row in the table as per the cron expression in that row? Each row's job should run simultaneously even if their schedules clash. The job would be to POST the id to a REST URL, receive data and store that data in other tables in my native PostgreSQL DB

Comment: Well, "possible" I'm sure, but we'd need to see much more detail before we could make any suggestions.  "Thousands" plural sounds like a big red flag to me.

Comment: anything is possible through coding, where is your code?